# CommanArgument passing numbers Unhandled excetion System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Please help and I am stuck.   I have a Stored procedure that fetches and populates a Grid.  I try to pass a number value in the Command argument and I get the unhandled exception as per my title.   I have tried looking at the DBML and don't see anything. Here is my code:

```
</asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="name"  HeaderText="Player" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="dsc" HeaderText="Desc." />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="cond" HeaderText="Cond." />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="maker" HeaderText="Make" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="year" HeaderText="Year" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="Price" DataFormatString="{0:C}"/>      
        <asp:BoundField DataField="qty" HeaderText="Qty." />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Buy">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Buy" ToolTip="Add to Cart" OnClientClick="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" CommandArgument='<% #Eval("name") + "," + Eval("price") + "," + Eval("pic") %>'></asp:Button>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

The Code Behind:

```
Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)
Dim commandName As String = btn.CommandName
Dim commandArg As String() = btn.CommandArgument.ToString.Split(",")
Dim argName As String = commandArg(0)
Dim argDsc As String = commandArg(1)
Dim argPrice As String = commandArg(2)
Dim argPic As String = commandArg(3)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the error occur when `Button2` is clicked? Are you sure the problem isn't with the `DataField="price"` databinding (did you try removing the `DataFormatString` attribute)?

Answer (score 0):

Given that `Price` is some type of monetary numeric format, you need to convert it to a string when concatenating your button `CommandArgument`.

```
<asp:Button ... CommandArgument='<% #Eval("name") + "," 
+ Eval("price").ToString() + ","
+ Eval("pic") %>'>
```